# Installing vim plugin vundle fails on fresh install

Tags: linux, vim, vundle

I'm trying to customize Vim on my VPS. I've done everything as described in many tutorials and README.md files.

So, apt-get vim, vim works
apt-get git
pull vim
created ~/.vimrc

and it looks like this:

```
" vim -u test/vimrc
set nocompatible
set nowrap
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vimrc/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'L9'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

My tree structure looks as it should:

```
.
└── bundle
    └── Vundle.vim
        ├── autoload
        │   ├── vundle
        │   │   ├── config.vim
        │   │   ├── installer.vim
        │   │   └── scripts.vim
        │   └── vundle.vim
        ├── changelog.md
        ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
        ├── doc
        │   └── vundle.txt
        ├── ftplugin
        │   └── vundlelog.vim
        ├── LICENSE-MIT.txt
        ├── README.md
        ├── README_ZH_CN.md
        ├── syntax
        │   └── vundlelog.vim
        └── test
            ├── files
            │   └── test.erl
            ├── minirc.vim
            └── vimrc
```

Now, according to manuals and README.md, I should run Vim, and it should load plugins, but no.

```
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line    8:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'L9'
line   12:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
```

I've tried to read a bit existing problems that people had, they all customized things a bit, changed default folders etc, but all my thing look exactly where they should be, I was trying defaults.

As well, I've seen that people are asking for the :scriptnames so here it goes:

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
7: ~/.vimrc
8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

Now, writing this here, I've noticed that obviously some default somewhere is putting things to /usr/share? Is that my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://vi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
set rtp+=~/.vimrc/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

in your vimrc, and this means your `Vundle.vim` is under `~/.vimrc/bundle/`. But `~/.vimrc` is listed in the result of `:scriptnames`. So if you followed instructions from Vundle.vim, I think you should change the above line to

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

if your `~/.vimrc` is a regular file and not a directory, and you have your `Vundle.vim` under `~/.vim/`.

Comment: Ahhh... So lame detail... :) I looked at it for hours, but constantly overlooked the fact it's the parent directory that has different name, not anything else.... Thanks @Yous